# dpkg lock cannot be resolved

Tags: command-line, apt

I get the following error:

```
 E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource
 temporarily unavailable)

 E: Unable to lock the administration
 directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

every time I try to install new software and then I tried to kill the process. So I typed in the command 'ps -A | grep apt-get' and get no response from it.

*How do I get rid of this lock?*

Comment: Also instead of typing `ps -A | grep apt-get` type `ps -A | grep apt`.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` isn't the only front-end application thing that uses `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`.

Things like Update Manager and the Software Centre, Synaptic and `aptitude` all have their own ways of interfacing with the Apt and dpkg databases.

To find out *what* has it open, you can use `fuser`:

```
sudo fuser -u /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then, if that's safe to kill (I'd advise people always check before using the `-k` flag), [you can kill it and delete the lockfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process).

Comment: I get 30+ results when running `sudo fuser -cu /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, and it's not even locked / in use now. And the `-cuk` flags immediately kill my login session & all programs

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah I copied over the example from the linked thread. I don't really understand the logic in the `-c` argument because it really breaks it. I've removed it.

Comment: That works well with just the `-c` flag, maybe something's changed since 2010 when that answer was written, I almost got the same kill problems as the other comments there (knowing what's "safe to kill" from just the `fuser` output isn't obvious ;-) And I'm wondering if there's something wrong with `lsof`, I'll post it as an alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `lsof <file>` seems to work too.

For example, if I have `synaptic` running (live):

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /cow
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/999/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
synaptic 20942 root   10uW  REG   0,18        0 39610 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then I know that `synaptic` with PID 20942 is what's opened the lock file, blocking other package management programs.